# How to vary spy results between each tests

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing some tests for an Angular component that has a dependency on a service.

This service has a `stageData` public member and I want to test that the component behaves correctly depending on the content of `stageData`.

Since I need to mock the service I created a spy and defined what it would return for stageData but I can't change this in each tests.

```
describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let component: ProgressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProgressComponent>;
  let progressStageService: any;
  const signStage = new StageCompletionModel();
  const inkStage = new StageCompletionModel();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    signStage.stage = Stage.Sign;
    inkStage.stage = Stage.Ink;

    progressStageService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ProgressStageService', ['getStageProgress']);
    progressStageService.stageData = [signStage];

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProgressComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: ProgressStageService, useValue: progressStageService } ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProgressComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should not display Ink stage when it is not in stageData', () => {
    const callToAction: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const stageLabels = callToAction.querySelectorAll('span.stage-label');
    expect(Array.from(stageLabels).some(sl => sl.textContent.includes('Ink'))).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should display Ink stage when it is in stageData', () => {
    const callToAction: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const stageLabels = callToAction.querySelectorAll('span.stage-label');

    progressStageService.stageData = [signStage, inkStage];
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(Array.from(stageLabels).some(sl => sl.textContent.includes('Ink'))).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I've tried many variations in my second test case but stageData always contains the data that it is set up with in the `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to split it between more `describes` when mocking the data. The first `fixture.detectChanges` in the 2nd `beforeEach` is what "bundles" the component and calls `ngOnInit`.

Try:

```
describe('ProgressComponent', () => {
  let component: ProgressComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProgressComponent>;
  let progressStageService: any;
  const signStage = new StageCompletionModel();
  const inkStage = new StageCompletionModel();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    signStage.stage = Stage.Sign;
    inkStage.stage = Stage.Ink;

    progressStageService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ProgressStageService', ['getStageProgress']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProgressComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: ProgressStageService, useValue: progressStageService } ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('getting a handle on the fixture');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProgressComponent);
    console.log(fixture);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // re-assign progressStageService to what was injected in the configureTestingModule
    // If you're using Angular 9, this should be .inject and not .get
    progressStageService = TestBed.get(ProgressStageService);
    // fixture.detectChanges(); => Remove fixture.detectChanges here
  });

 describe('stageData is [signStage]', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      // assign stageData to the service that was injected
      progressStageService.stageData = [signStage];
      fixture.detectChanges();
   });

  it('should not display Ink stage when it is not in stageData', () => {
    const callToAction: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const stageLabels = callToAction.querySelectorAll('span.stage-label');
    expect(Array.from(stageLabels).some(sl => sl.textContent.includes('Ink'))).toBeFalsy();
  });
 });

 describe('stageData is [signStage, inkStage]', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      // assign stageData to the service that was injected
      progressStageService.stageData = [signStage, inkStage];
      fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should display Ink stage when it is in stageData', () => {
    const callToAction: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const stageLabels = callToAction.querySelectorAll('span.stage-label');
    expect(Array.from(stageLabels).some(sl => 
sl.textContent.includes('Ink'))).toBeTruthy();
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that stageData is undefined in ProgressComponent and that fixture is undefined in my tests.

Comment: I have added two `console.log`s before getting a handle on `fixture`. Make sure they run when executing your tests. As for `stageData` is undefined in `ProgressComponent`, I though `stageData` live in `ProgressStageService`?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say, `stageData` is undefined when it's being used from `ProgressStageService` in `ProgressComponent`. I've added the two console.log statements. The first one is working but the second isn't being called, even if I put a string in the statement. I'm also getting this error in the console `zone-evergreen.js:2857 GET ng:///ProgressComponent/%C9%B5fac.js net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. Currently investigating.

Comment: I can get the errors to go away by setting `progressStageService.stageData = [];` in the first `beforeEach` but then I'm back again to when it's not updating. I'm thinking I might just write two seperate `describe`s. It's ugly but I can't get it to work.

Comment: That's weird how the second one is not being called, but yes, try two separate describes. What I presented "should" have been what is two separate describes but this is with less code.

Comment: I just split them up so everything is duplicated. I feel there is a better way to do this.

Comment: My "thinking" is that the first `fixture.detectChanges` is what stands up the component and calls `ngOnInit`, so modifying `stageData` before standing it up should have done the trick but I am not sure why it did not work.